# Does emit copy its arguments?

Tags: qt

I want to know about `emit`. Does it duplicate data?

If I have to pass a 1MB byte array through it, how many copies of that byte array will exist in memory?

Comment: A way to look if you use one of the container listed [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/implicit-sharing.html)

Comment: Discover it by yourself :) take into account that emit is defined as follows: #define emit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends on how your signals are connected to slots.

If you use the default connection, `Qt::DirectConnection`, and the two `QObject`s are in the same thread, then the parameters are treated as if you were calling function in the usual way according to how you defined the parameters(pass-by-reference or pass-by-value).

If you connect using `Qt::QueuedConnection` or you are connected between threads, then the parameter arguments are copied and handed over to a special `QEvent` and added to the receiving thread's event queue. This will then be processed by the receiving thread when it gets the chance.

Comment: I think that you wrong (see any moc-generated code). Even if you pass a parameters inside same thread (via reference) Qt pass it by value, never by reference. But almost Qt containers / data types are using COW - thats why passing by value doesn't require extra resources.

Comment: @Dmitry Sazanov: Nope, for direct connections, nothing is copied when using references for both signal and slot signatures. The moc code takes addresses of the arguments. Where do you see the copies?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how the connections are made, and how you pass the parameters.

1. Pass by value (i.e. `signals: void foo(Bar);`)

   - A normal C++ function call would generate one copy (to copy the `Bar` from caller to callee).
   - A direct-connected signal/slot invocation will generate two copies: the emit function generated by `moc` is called (one copy, same as the one above), "packages" the parameter and calls `QMetaObject::activate` which ends up calling your class's `qt_static_metacall`, which invokes the slot (as a normal function call), incurring a second copy.
   - A queue-connected signal/slot invocation will generate three copies. In the calling context, the emit function call itself as above, and a copy of the parameter into an event. In the receiver context, the same `qt_static_metacall` invocation of the slot.
2. Pass by const reference (i.e. `signals: void foo(Bar const&);`)

   - Normal C++ function call: no copy.
   - Direct-connected signal/slot invocation: no copy.
   - Queue-connected signal/slot invocation: one copy, the one into the event object described above
3. Pass by (non-const) reference (i.e. `signals: void foo(Bar&);`)

   - Normal C++ function call: no copy.
   - Direct-connected signal/slot invocation: no copy.
   - Queue-connected signal/slot invocation: not possible (AFAIK).

The copy into an event is mentioned in [the docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum):

> With queued connections, the parameters must be of types that are known to Qt's meta-object system, because **Qt needs to copy the arguments to store them in an event** behind the scenes.

Now the real question is: does this matter?

If you're using a Qt container class that uses [implicit sharing](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/implicit-sharing.html), it won't really matter in usual cases - the payload won't be copied unless required. So the copies shouldn't have a significant impact on overall performance in general.

If you're not using implicit sharing, then passing massive objects by value probably isn't the right choice in the first place, but a slot invocation would be more expensive than a plain function call. Direct-connected slots and pass-by-const-ref will behave the same as normal function calls, but queued slots will be more expensive.

Comment: It should also be noted that `emit` is an empty macro, meaning that emitting a signal means calling that function, so *at least* normal function argument semantics apply, even in the case of direct connections (value vs reference, move semantics, copy elision, and everything else.)

Comment: @NikosC.: thanks for your comment, made me look into this a bit more and it's not as straightforward as I initially though. Updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

All Qt containers implement "copy on write" pattern. So when you are passing container by value nothing is copied until you will use none-const method of this container.

So bottom line is: it is safe (it will not double memory consumption) to pass large qt containers through signals and slots.